# Integer formatter for string ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nslog

I want to know what will be the result of the following code

```
NSString *str = @"0";
NSString *str1 = @"12";
NSLog(@"str int value %d, %d",str, str1);
```

Result  I got is 18036, 18052

I used a wrong format specifier in my code and came across this weird result. I fixed it later through. But I wanted to know what exactly it print out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> `NSLog(@"str int value %d, %d",str, str1);`

You're passing pointers to strings as the parameters, but the format string specifies integers. A good guess is that the pointers will be interpreted as integers, so the output will depend on where in memory the strings happen to be allocated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it printed out the string pointer address

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I though so, but I wanted to know for sure what it is displaying.

Comment: The question was "But I wanted to know what exactly it print out." I suppose my answer was pretty close